# How to get HTML content of Microsoft Word document?

Tags: jquery, html, ms-word, office-js, word-addins

I have used the below code in order to get the `HTML` content of `Microsoft Word Document`:

```
Word.run(function (context) {
                    var body = context.document.body;
                    context.load(body, 'html');
                    console.log(body.getHtml());

                    return context.sync().then(function () {
                        console.log("Content is fetched:", body.getHtml().value);
                    });
                })
                .catch(function(error){
                    // Log additional information, if applicable:
                    if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                        console.log(error.debugInfo);
                    }
                });
```

Here in the above code `body.getHtml()` prints an object which inside of it there is the content I expect. To retrieve that data I use `.value` to get actual `HTML` content, but it gives the below error:

> There is an error in word data fetch RichApi.Error: "The value of the
>   result object has not been loaded yet. Before reading the value
>   property, call "context.sync()" on the associated request context."

I have issued `context.sync()`, but the same error appears. Any help here?

Comment: Which line of code is producing the error? I'd bet it's the first `console.log` because you try to read the html *before* you execute `context.sync`. Comment out `console.log(body.getHtml());` and see if it works better...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fundamental issue here is that you get the HTML with  a method call, you don't load stuff like this, its implicit, but you want to make sure you sync before getting the values :)

this is how it works check sample below:

```js
Word.run(function (context) {
        var myHTML  = context.document.body.getHtml();
    
        return context.sync()
            .then(function() {
                console.log(myHTML.value);
            });
    });
```